# Separating multiple rows of a select query using delimiter (Oracle)

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

I have a query

```
SELECT originating_timestamp
FROM sys.x$dbgalertext
WHERE message_text LIKE '%Starting up%' 
  and to_char(ORIGINATING_TIMESTAMP,'DD-MON-YY') = to_char(systimestamp,'DD-MON-YY');
```

The output in a linux script is as below:

```
09-OCT-17 04.59.33.758 AM -05:00 09-OCT-17 05.03.22.645 AM -05:00
```

there are two rows above each starting by date.

I would like to have the output like

```
09-OCT-17 04.59.33.758 AM -05:00;09-OCT-17 05.03.22.645 AM -05:00
```

This is just two rows, there can be many more, I would like it so that **every row is separated via delimiter**.

I have tried few options like

1) using listagg:

```
select listagg(originating_timestamp,', ') within group(order by originating_timestamp) csv
from sys.x$dbgalertext 
WHERE message_text LIKE '%Starting up%' 
  and to_char(ORIGINATING_TIMESTAMP,'DD-MON-YY') = to_char(systimestamp,'DD-MON-YY');
```

But this gives error:
ERROR at line 1:

```
ORA-01489: result of string concatenation is too long
```

2) using XMLAGG:

```
SELECT RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(E,originating_timestamp,';').EXTRACT('//text()') ORDER BY originating_timestamp).GetClobVal(),',') AS LIST
FROM sys.x$dbgalertext 
WHERE message_text LIKE '%Starting up%' 
  and to_char(ORIGINATING_TIMESTAMP,'DD-MON-YY')= to_char(systimestamp,'DD-MON-YY');
```

But the output is like :

```
2017-10-09T04:59:33.758-05:00;2017-10-09T05:03:22.645-05:00;
```

Which is also not correct.

e.g. `Select username from dba_users`. Suppose there are 10 users, i want those 10 usernames to be separated via delimiter.

Comment: Do you need comma separated string ?

Comment: yes comma , semicolon ... any delimiter between the two outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below two anonymous block example which may be helpful to solve your problem :

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000
DECLARE
res VARCHAR2(100);
tmp VARCHAR2(100);
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
      IF i != 10 THEN     
         select 'a' ||',' into tmp from dual;
      ELSE
          select 'a' into tmp from dual;
      END IF;

      res := concat(res,tmp);
   END LOOP;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(res);
END;
/
```

Second :

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000
DECLARE
res VARCHAR2(1000);
tmp VARCHAR2(1000);
BEGIN
   FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
      IF i != 10 THEN     
         select TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYYHH24:MI') || ','  into tmp from dual;
      ELSE
          select TO_CHAR(sysdate,'DD-MON-YYYYHH24:MI') into tmp from dual;
      END IF; 
      res := concat(res,tmp);
   END LOOP;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(res);
END;
/
```

You should replace my query select with yours and of course the format of date you wanna get and replace comma with your desire character .

To make it working properly i wanna suggest you to create a cursor :

```
 SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE 1000000
            DECLARE
            res VARCHAR2(100);
            tmp VARCHAR2(100);
            cont NUMBER;
            CURSOR C_1 IS
              SELECT to_char(originating_timestamp,'your date format') 
             originating_timestamp
             FROM sys.x$dbgalertext
             WHERE message_text LIKE '%Starting up%' 
            and to_char(ORIGINATING_TIMESTAMP,'DD-MON-YY') = to_char(systimestamp,'DD-MON-YY');
            BEGIN
              cont := 0;
               FOR C_row IN C_1 LOOP
                  IF cont != C_1%rowcount THEN    
                   tmp :=  C_row.originating_timestamp ||',';
                   res := concat(res,tmp);
                  ELSE
                      tmp :=  C_row.originating_timestamp;
                      res := concat(res,tmp);
                  END IF;
                  cont := cont +1;
               END LOOP;
               DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(res);
            END;
            /
```

Comment: Hey Frank, Thanks a lot, but there is single query and it is giving multiple rows in one go, i want those rows to be separated via delimiter.
e.g.
Select username from dba_users;
Suppose there are 10 users, i want those 10 usernames to be separated via delimiter. 
Help me out please.

Comment: I edited the answer  , you will solve your problem using a cursor and iterate through it

Comment: @PankajSingh. I dont think there is a need for temp table and so much intermediate work arounds.